# sotre data in mongodb via mongoose schema with not passing value of unique true key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

i have a mongoose schema like this :-

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
email: {type: String, required: true,unique: true},
mobNum: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
username: {type: String, unique: true},
dob:{ type: Date},
isTempUser: {type: String, default: true},
mobNumVerified: {type: Boolean, default: false},
emailVerified: {type: Boolean, default: false},
registrationComplete: {type: Boolean, default: false}})
```

When i try to save data in db with this code:-

```
                    let newUser = User();
                    newUser.name = name;
                    newUser.email = email;
                    newUser.mobNum = mobNum;
                    newUser.save();
```

when i run server and hit my api for register new user only frist time data save successfully in mongodb when i try different value save in db i got and error

that's :-

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: okhlee-kdb-promoter.users index: username_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.MongoError.create (D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
    at toError (D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:139:22)
    at D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:659:23
    at handleCallback (D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
    at D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\unordered.js:465:9
    at handleCallback (D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
    at resultHandler (D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\unordered.js:413:5)
    at D:\Okhlee.com\KDB Promoter backend\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:461:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: okhlee-kdb-promoter.users index: username_1 dup key: { : null }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: okhlee-kdb-promoter.users index: username_1 dup key: { : null }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

As i know this error is related to duplicate value of **username** but i when save data in db i'm not store **username** on frist api i save **username** next time when user come on our webpage .

So please solve this error.

Comment: Add both the data you have used . Also, the MongoDB version and Mongoose Version

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB a [unique field can not be empty in multiple records](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field). If your user will not provide username at first but you still need the field to be unique, then you can store a random string or mobile num or email as username in the first attempt. I think that will work for you.

If you wish to create a random string and assign it to username, you can try the following using crypto:

```
  let newUser = User();
  newUser.name = name;
  newUser.email = email;
  newUser.mobNum = mobNum;
  require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(err, buffer) {
        if(err) { throw err }
        username = buffer.toString('hex');
        newUser  = username;
        newUser.save();
  });
```